# Removing duplicate rows created by ST_Intersects in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, st-intersects, duplication

I want to basically take one spatial table of polygons and determine if any of the polygons interest with another table of polygons and save the results in a new table with a new column saving the result as true or false. The script below works:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table AS
SELECT parcels.*, COALESCE(ST_Intersects(parcels.wkb_geometry, flood.wkb_geometry), false) AS intersects
FROM parcels LEFT OUTER JOIN flood ON ST_Intersects(parcels.wkb_geometry, flood.wkb_geometry);
```

However I do get duplicates when a polygon from the first table is intersected by multiple polygons from the second table. As seen below:

[image]

I would like to only have one entry per polygon, even if it has been intersected multiple times. I have been removing duplicate rows as a work around, but I wanted to know if there is a more elegant way of doing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add **DISTINCT** to your select statement that should return what you are looking for.

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table AS
SELECT DISTINCT parcels.*, COALESCE(ST_Intersects(parcels.wkb_geometry, flood.wkb_geometry), false) AS intersects
FROM parcels LEFT OUTER JOIN flood ON ST_Intersects(parcels.wkb_geometry, flood.wkb_geometry);
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to specify which column should be DISTINCT e.g. the IDs?

Comment: Nope, no need to. The whole record is added multiple times, so we can just pick out the distinct ones. I tried on a test run to be sure.